# How to format text color in xterm.js

Tags: javascript, console.log, xtermjs

I am using xterm.js as a web console. 
While it allows to change the console color and background, I could not find any way to write each line with different colors. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

So, although it is a bit unclear from xterm.js documentation, the way to use mixed colors in `write` or `writeln` command, is to use ANSI colors described in **theme** configuration, for example:

```
  terminal.writeln('\x1b[1;31m' + 'User:'+ '\x1b[37m' + 'my name');
```

Will print the text in **red** and **white**

Comment: Hi, @Yuvals  can you please tell how not to make it BOLD. color seems to appear but it is appearing bold
https://gyazo.com/e20cc5c5a26d570a5a967a7d17d79fef